# Abp.Zero.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutra l, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.”

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, typeloadexception

```
System.TypeLoadException:
“Method 'Get' in type 'Abp.DynamicEntityProperties.
DynamicEntityPropertyValueStore' from assembly
 'Abp.Zero.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutra
l, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.”
```

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you share more information about what you are trying to do, which code base are you trying to run; when do you come across this error etc. And sharing some code piece would help.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I'm using the latest version 6.0.0 angular template

Comment: I think you should implement it

Comment: In my case it was a version conflict between the `HangFire.SqlServer`, `Abp.HangFire.AspNetCore` and `Abp`

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue too
i have deleted Package Abp.Web.Common and the problem is solved